# Why do I need to use quotation marks ("") to call a table in PostGIS? I remember not to need it in other exercises

Tags: postgis, table

When I try to run the following code I get an error that disappear when I call the tables using quotation marks. I remember having run tables before without it.

`select cine as INE from "Nucleos_capital"`

Comment: This could be the answer : https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/postgresql/short-guides/quoting-rules#double-quotes

Comment: You have faced a case that requires to use "SQL delimited identifiers". Basic SQL thing with no connection to GIS.

Comment: @J.R Thanks you for your reply that works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PostgreSQL DB table names should be (are by default) all-lower-case. You can, however, create a table braking this rule, but then the only way you can refer to it is by enclosing the table name in double quotes.
In other words,if your table was named **n**ucleos_capital you could `select * from nucleos_capital`. Now it is **N**ucleos_capital, hence the need to use quotes.
You can rename it: `alter table "Nucleos_capital" rename to nucleos_capital` (mind the use of quotes!)